# How do you deal with Typescript typed local state variables on load in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I recently started working on a React project that uses Typescript and there's one particular issues I've run into that I can't figure out how it's handles in typescript. It's pretty common for react projects and I'm sure theres a way to deal with it but haven't found docs that have been helpful.

```
import * as React from "react"; 
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux-consumer";
import { loadFoo } from "reduxActions/action";

type FooType = {
  hello: HelloWorldType; 
  world: HelloWorldType;
}

type HelloWorldType = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  // On load foo value hasn't been loaded yet. Initialize it to empty
  const [currentFoo, setCurrentFoo] = React.useState<HelloWorldType>(); 
  const foo = useSelector(state => state.foo);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadFoo());
  }, [loadFoo]);

  return (
    <div>
      <InputComponent currentFoo={currentFoo} setCurrentFoo={setCurrentFoo}/>
    </div>
  ); 
}

export type setCurrentFoo = React.Dispatch<
  React.SetStateAction<HelloWorldType>
>;

type InputComponentPropType = {
 currentFoo: HelloWorldType;
 setCurrentFoo: setCurrentFoo;
}

const InputComponent = (props: InputComponentPropType) => {
   const {currentFoo, setCurrentFoo} = props;
    return (
         <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            id="hello" 
            name={currentFoo.name} 
            value={currentFoo.value} 
            onChange={e => {
              setCurrentFoo(currentFoo)
            }
         />
    );
}
```

In the above code example my `currentFoo` variables needs to be of type `HelloWorld` but my issues is I don't actually have the value until I load it from my redux state or fetch from the api. In this case I'll get the Typescript error in `MyComponent` and `InputComponent` that type `HelloWorld` is not compatible with type of `undefined`.

How do you initialize the `currentFood` state variable with turning it into a a chain of component where you have to support type `undefined` everywhere? Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

In `MyComponent`, you can define `currentFoo` as `HelloWorldType` or `undefined` and in `InputComponentPropType` you can mark the `currentFoo` property as optional and while setting the `name` or `value` of the input field, keep a check. If `currentFoo` is not present then assign it to some default value. I have assigned it to empty string below, but you can assign it with any value.

```
import * as React from "react"; 
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux-consumer";
import { loadFoo } from "reduxActions/action";

type FooType = {
  hello: HelloWorldType; 
  world: HelloWorldType;
}

type HelloWorldType = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  // On load foo value hasn't been loaded yet. Initialize it to empty
  const [currentFoo, setCurrentFoo] = React.useState<HelloWorldType|undefined>(); 
  const foo = useSelector(state => state.foo);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadFoo());
  }, [loadFoo]);

  return (
    <div>
      <InputComponent currentFoo={currentFoo} setCurrentFoo={setCurrentFoo}/>
    </div>
  ); 
}

export type setCurrentFoo = React.Dispatch<
  React.SetStateAction<HelloWorldType>
>;

type InputComponentPropType = {
 currentFoo?: HelloWorldType; // '?' makes this property/field optional
 setCurrentFoo: setCurrentFoo;
}

const InputComponent = (props: InputComponentPropType) => {
   const {currentFoo, setCurrentFoo} = props;
    return (
         <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            id="hello" 
            name={currentFoo?.name || ""} 
            value={currentFoo?.value || ""} 
            onChange={e => {
              setCurrentFoo(currentFoo)
            }
         />
    );
}
```

**OR**

A much simpler way is to just initialize the `currentFoo` inside `MyComponent` with a dummy value

```
  const [currentFoo, setCurrentFoo] = React.useState<HelloWorldType>({ name: "", value: "" });
```